# How to concat two vars in while loop

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I'd like to construct a 'union all' query with a while loop.

I've already tried += concatenation but doesn't work.

```
DECLARE @cnt1 int , @concat nvarchar(max), @qry nvarchar(500);
SET @cnt1 = 1;
WHILE @cnt1 < 99 
BEGIN 
SET @qry = 'select name_' + CAST(@cnt1 AS CHAR) + ' , name2_' + CAST(@cnt1 AS CHAR) + ', m.state1 FROM table1 P left join table2 M on M.name = P.name_' + CAST(@cnt1 AS CHAR) + ' where p.nb > 1'; 
SET @cnt1 = @cnt1 + 1; 
SET @concat += ' UNION ALL ' + @qry 
END 
EXEC sp_executesql @concat
```

@concat is still empty at the end of the loop...

Thank you vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `@concat` isn't initialized, the default value is `null`. Concatenating a value with `null` results in `null`, so no progress is made in your loop. Initializing it to an empty string:

```
declare @Concat as NVarChar(max) = N'';
```

will fix the problem.

Tip: The default length of a `Char`, `VarChar`, `NChar` or `NVarChar` is one character most of the time. When it is the target type of a `Cast` or `Convert` then it is 30 characters. Best practice: Always specify a length.